# Is there any component equivalent in LWC or AURA for apex:actionPoller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, actionpoller, polling

Is there any component equivalent in LWC or AURA for `apex:actionPoller` ?

I know that we could achieve the functionality of `apex:actionPoller` by `setTimeout()` method, but I wonder if we have any component in the Component Library or method which covers this either in LWC or Aura?

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent would be lightning:empApi/lightning-emp-api. Instead of asking for updates, it's much easier to listen for updates. If you need a polling mechanism, use setInterval/setTimeout. However, there's almost always a better way to deal with server-side updates, such as event-driven notifications.